# A syntactician "must-read" list

Tags: syntax, reference-request, methodology

I'm a (mostly) self-taught linguist. I was always interested in syntax so I started with Carnie's (2013) Syntax: A generative introduction + few interviews with Chomsky (where I got the general idea of the philosophy behind his research and learned about PoS argument). First I was satisfied with the contents of the book, but after g oogling and reading this and that for about a year I started to question literally every possible explanation of various phenomena ( e.g. why movement in the first place? why autonomous syntax? etc.)

This made me read a few more papers and a couple of books, along with a very good blog Faculty of Language. I needed historical background, knowledge ABOUT the methodology used in modern syntax research and a lot more stuff. This is where it got really serious and hard. I also encountered a lot of irrelevant work and wasted some time.

By now I've studied enough to figure out the most influential works but few years ago I knew nothing about them. So I wonder if there is a such a list of titles one could recommend to any beginner, and, even better, an ordered list so that the beginner doesn't get confused with terminology in different theories (e.g. since ST - GB - MP of the generative enterprise are pretty different). I'd like to know other people's ideas.

Comment: I understand that you've expressed an interest in syntax; I don't understand what question you want answered. Can you clarify? Are you asking for the most influential works in syntax? Or do you just want people to post their personal favorites, in which case there are no good answers or bad answers.

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough - by now I've studied enough to figure out the most influential works but few years ago I knew nothing about them. So I wonder if there is a such a list of titles one can recommend to any beginner, and, even better, an ordered list so that the beginner doesn't get confused with terminology in different theories (e.g. since ST - GB - MP of generative enterprise are pretty different). I'd like to know other people's ideas.

Comment: I see, so it looks like you're looking for a historical guide to terminology, of sorts. I think that is actually a feature of ST and descendants, that the technical words are stable but their definitions change, for example c-command.

Comment: Asking for recommendations goes against the Stack Exchange model sorry. Questions should aim to be objectively and conclusively answered, but this cannot.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Even reference requests? I can see how this could be a helpful and popular question (maybe with some editing).

Comment: @Ivan If it's a tight request then that can be okay, but this is too broad.

Comment: The two answers so far encourages the OP to explore some approaches radically different from the ones he's used to. I think that's a mistake, not because these are necessarily bad frameworks, but because he's asking for generative references.

Comment: We could put it like this - the ultimate guide that takes you from zero to a graduate level in a fastest way (and limit ourselves to GG)

Comment: @Vectk, your comment suggests you don't know what "generative" means.  Chomsky discussed it in **Aspects of the Theory of Syntax**.  Both the references I gave in my answer are about generative syntax.

Comment: @GregLee, I question the premise that GPSG satisfies the Mentalist Claim part of the Aspects definition.

Comment: @user6726 I don't know what "the Mentalist Claim" is.  My recollection is that Chomsky said the "generative" in "generative grammar" meant characterize explicitly, in the same sense that an algebraic function generates a curve when graphed.  There is no mentalist claim there.  Chomsky makes mentalist claims, but that doesn't mean every generative grammarian must also.

Comment: @GregLee We do not need to refer back to Aspects to find out what anything 'meant', as it is outdated. A generative approach to syntax is meant to shed light on the structure of Universal Grammar/Language Faculty. To the extent that this is the aim, generative proposals should be able to account for cross-linguistic data. I believe both sources you give focus on English. Also, my understanding is that Pullum does not believe English to be context-free anymore.  Higgonbotham (1984) proves this, so GPSG is outdated as well.

Comment: To the OP, I wrote an [answer](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/13110/9616) a while back recommending some generative texts.  I think Core Syntax by Adger would be ideal for you.  However, do buy the book instead of downloading from research gate.  The latter version is riddled with typos.

Comment: @Vectk, Of course Pullum's beliefs about whether English is context free have no bearing at all on whether GPSG is a generative theory.  It is.  But just to set the record straight, Pullum accepts an argument that certain languages other than English (a Swiss-German dialect, Norwegian, ...) are not context free.  The crucial constructions do not occur in English, so this is not relevant to whether English is context free.

Comment: @GregLee, the first section of *Aspects*, ch. 1 is entitled "Generative Grammars as Theories of Linguistic Competence". Insofar as Chomsky coined the term "generative grammar", we should understand "generative grammar" to refer to the thing that *he* defined, just as we understand "Natural Phonology" to be the theory of phonology defined by David Stampe, and "Arc Pair Grammar" to be the theory defined by Johnson and Postal, etc.

Comment: @user6726, I'm fine with Chomsky defining "generative", but how does he define it?  He used "generate" for the relationship between a formal grammar (e.g. context free grammar) and the language it characterizes in his work back in the fifties, and it is still used in this sense in the literature on formal languages.  A grammar that generates a language is a generative grammar.  I really don't think Chomsky has ever proposed to redefine the term "generative".  If so, could I have a quote, please?

Comment: p. 4: "A grammar of a language purports to be a description of the ideal speaker-hearer's intrinsic competence. If the grammar is, furthermore, perfectly explicit -- in other words, if it does not rely on the intelligence of the understanding reader but rather provides an explicit analysis of his contribution --- we may (somewhat redundantly) call it a *generative grammar*".

Comment: @user6726, that is an apropos quote.  It says just what I have said here about "generative".  It's explicit.  It does not rely on the intelligence of the understanding reader -- this means there is an algorithm that connects the grammar with each sentence that it generates.  And of course there is such an algorithm for a context free grammar, and hence for GPSG.  GPSG is a generative grammar which, in its theoretical aspect, was invented by Chomsky!  How could it not be generative?  (I admit that one could raise doubts in this regard about the theory of McCawley's **SPHE**.)

Comment: I see, so your objection is that you weren't claiming that GPSG is an example of generative grammar.

Comment: @user6726, What??  Are you trying to confuse me?  I did claim that GPSG is a generative grammar.  And I claim that it is generative according to Chomsky's definition, which you were kind enough to look up for us.  It has nothing to do with mentalism.  Nothing.  Chomsky proposes that human languages have generative grammars which are mental objects.  It does not follow that "generative" somehow means "mental".

Comment: @GregLee, focus on the words "a description of the ideal speaker-hearer's intrinsic competence". That is what mentalism refers to.

Comment: @user6726, no, that isn't what mentalism refers to.  If you're a mentalist, then you think competence is described by a mental object.  If you're not a mentalist, you think it's described in some other way. In any case, this stuff about competence has to do with what grammar is, not what "generative" means.  Surely you not trying to tell us that every grammarian must be a mentalist, by definition?!

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Greg Lee that McCawley is the place to go for the canonical generative treatment of English syntax and that GPSG is the generative counterpart to that. However, things have moved on since then. I would further recommend looking into **Unification Grammars** (which is very much at the heart of minimalism under a different name) and **Construction Grammars**.

For the former, I recommend starting with Ivan Sag et al.'s [Unification and Grammatical Theory](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/sagetal-1986.pdf). And my personal bible on construction grammar is William Croft's [Radical Construction Grammar: Syntactic Theory in Typological Perspective](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Radical-Construction-Grammar-Typological-Perspective/dp/0198299540/) but Adele Goldberg's [Constructions](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Constructions-Construction-Approach-Structure-Cognitive/dp/0226300862) are also a good introduction. Of course, [Fillmore's work](http://journals.linguisticsociety.org/proceedings/index.php/BLS/article/viewFile/1794/1566) on this was very foundational and elucidates the initial motivations behind the construction movement. Croft does a very good job in the introductory chapter of setting out the construction grammar space and its relationship to kindred frameworks such as the Lexical Functional Grammar.

What you will find with construction grammar is that many of the problems that the generativist frameworks deal with simply disappear as syntax and semantics are brought closer together. I think Langacker is the best author in this respect.

However, you should also not skip **dependency grammars** if you want to get a comprehensive view of syntactic theory. The work of [Sgall and Hajicova](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Meaning-Sentence-Semantic-Pragmatic-Aspects/dp/9027718385) (full disclosure - both were my teachers) has been leading the way in recent decades (e.g. with [this recent publication](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dependency-Linguistics-linguistic-dependency-structures/dp/9027255989)). This work will also highlight the importance of **information structure** or **topic-focus articulation** (something none of the other frameworks are concerned with - except perhaps in a round about way construction grammar).

This is still a very selective overview, there are dozens of grammatical frameworks within these broad trends: generative (constituency), generative (dependency), constructional. With many more cutting across such as unification or information structure. You could spend a lifetime cataloging them. But I think the reading list above might give you a sense of the scope of the project.

**Update**
Tim Osborne reminded me in the comments that  [Lucien Tesniere's "Elements of Structural Syntax"](http://%20Lucien%20Tensiere's) is now available in English translation, so that should definitely go on the list. He is the foundation on which all later dependency grammar frameworks explicitly build.

This also reminded me that Jan Firbas' [Functional Sentence Perspective in Written and Spoken Communication](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Functional-Sentence-Perspective-Communication-Language/dp/0521373085/) would make for a great introduction to information structure.

Comment: I am happy to see a recommendation to have a look at dependency grammars. But if one is going to recommend a book on dependency syntax, it should be Lucien Tensiere's "Elements of Structural Syntax" (1959/2015) (full disclosure, I translated it to English).

Comment: Funnily enough, I was debating whether to put Tesniere on the list but was not sure if there was much in English by him. He was certainly high on our reading list when we were taught dependency grammar. I've now updated the recommendation.

Comment: According to your reference *Unification and Grammatical Theory*, GPSG is a unification grammar.  So this is not exactly "moving on" from GPSG.  It's an attempt to construct an umbrella for contemporary non-transformational theories of syntax.

Comment: You are right GPSG was a broadly unificationist framework. When I think of unification, I think mostly of the more lexical approaches like HPSG or UCG. Perhaps in a technical sense, I was clumsy in the wording, but in all other respects I can hardly think of a better epithet to GPSG than 'things have moved on'.

Comment: Regarding topic-focus articulation: According to many analyses, topic/focus appear to be an overt (postposition-marked) feature of Japanese. Do you know whether someone has tried to discuss Japanese topics from a dependency-grammar perspective?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [The Syntactic Phenomena of English](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Syntactic_Phenomena_of_English.html?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC) by James McCawley.  It's the best book on syntax I've ever read, and I used it at least twice for intermediate level courses on syntax.  It's a book for grown-ups, and it's about doing syntax, not about methodology or syntactic theory.  (There is theory there, which I don't much agree with, personally, but it doesn't matter.)

You're certainly right to question whether there is syntactic movement.  I don't think there is (despite my above recommendation).  You might want to look at [Generalized Phrase Structure Grammar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674344561), which reconstructs the main parts of the transformational analysis of English without appeal to syntactic movement.  That is also a book for grown-ups.

Comment: I agree with Greg's recommendations. And for history, try [_The Linguistics Wars_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics_Wars), by Randy  Allen Harris.

Comment: What about dependency grammars? Dependency-based syntax represents a much different way of doing syntax, and yet most theoretical linguists who do phrase structure grammar overlook dependency syntax. McCawley (1997), for instance, only mentions dependency syntax in passing, and Gazdar et al.'s book on Generalized Phrase Structure Grammar does not mention dependency syntax (at least it's not listed in the index). See my comment further below.

Comment: I don't think dependency grammar is different at all.  One of the very early results in the study of context free grammar was a proof that dependency grammar is just another equivalent to context free phrase structure grammar.  Notations are often mistaken for theories in linguistics.  This is why McCawley and Gazdar et al. don't bother with it. (McCawley does discuss the notion *head*, and a feature Head is used in GPSG.)

Comment: My experience is that those who have not spent much time learning dependency syntax make statements like that. Dependency syntax limits the number of nodes in the structure to the number of elements (words) in the string at hand. This is a major limitation on how one understands and explores syntax. The dependency structures are much flatter than in most versions of constituency syntax. C-command as it it is commonly understood is, for instance, not available in dependency syntax. The layered (i.e. tall) structures that are common in constituency syntax are not available.

Comment: @TimOsborne, did Tesniere really say this about limiting the number of nodes?  I don't recall that.  If he did, how does this bear on what I said about dependency grammar being provably equivalent to context free grammar?

Comment: No, Tesniere did not say that, but other dependency grammars have said it, e.g. Covington, Kahane, Hellwig, Carnie, etc. If you'd like me to produce exact citations where the one-to-one point is stated, I can do so (contact me via email: tjo3ya@yahoo.com). Tesniere, however, was not aware of the difference between dependency and constituency. That distinction was not established until the 1960s during the reception of Tesniere's work. Tesniere's grammar was in fact a hybrid, employing both dependency and constituency on a massive scale.

Comment: @TimOsborne, no, that's okay.  I accept that others besides you have proposed this revision to dependency grammar.  My remarks about the equivalency to CF grammar did not concern this revised version.

Comment: What do you mean by "revision of dependency grammar"? Your understanding of DG seems to be different from mine. What is, in your view, the primary distinguishing trait between dependency- and constituency-based systems?

Comment: @TimOsborne, I'm just going by what you just told me.  You and certain others have proposed a restriction not in Tesniere's version of DG.  That's a revision, isn't it?  The demonstration that was published long ago that DG is a CFG, I assume was based on Tesniere's version, not the revised version you're telling me about now.  Maybe that's wrong -- you tell me.  What did I think the distinction was between DG and CFG?  None.  Isn't that's what I said above?  No real difference. But if you tell me that you and others have restricted dependency grammar so that it's not equivalent, I believe you

Comment: Which demonstration do you mean? I know that some have proposed that DG is weakly equivalent to CFG. Gaifmann did this back in the 1960s, I think. To my knowledge, however, almost no one has claimed that DG is strongly equivalent to CFG.

Comment: My greater concern is that DG is being misrepresented. Some who have little exposure to DG jump to claims about equivalency as a means to quickly move on. This does damage to DG, since it does not acknowledge that dependency-based systems are really quite different from constituency-based systems.

Comment: @TimOsborne, it's probably Gaifman's proof I'm thinking of.  Yes, it would have been weak equivalence.  (I've never been able to make sense of strong equivalence.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have become sceptical about the Chomskian syntax, you may be interested in constructionist approaches to grammar. Two books I can recommend are [*Cognitive Grammar*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198700334) by John R. Taylor and [*Constructions at work*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199268525) by Adele Goldberg. William Croft's [*Radical Construction Grammar*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002EVOT78) is another important work on this topic.

Note that different books use different terminology, what Goldberg calls a *construction* is more or less an equivalent of Cognitive Grammar's *symbolic unit*. But all in all they are very similar; there is a bit of discussion of the differences between constructionist approaches at the end of Goldberg's book.

Answer (score 1):

Learn some formal language theory via Sipser's Intro to the Theory of Computation. Having the background will be useful when dealing with Minimalist Grammars and their parsers.